# Orchard Feature Item Slider

Tags: orchardcms, orchard-modules

I'm trying to find out where the MOdule Feauture Item Slider in Orchard stored it's ImgUrl, I don't see any field that store its image in the table.

```
     .Select(fi => new FeaturedItemViewModel {
                Headline = fi.Headline,
                SubHeadline = fi.SubHeadline,
                LinkUrl = fi.LinkUrl,
                SeparateLink = fi.SeparateLink,
                LinkText = fi.LinkText,
                ImagePath = fi.Fields.Single(f => f.Name == "Picture").Storage.Get<string>(""),
                SlideNumber = ++slideNumber
            }).ToList();
```

What is this field?
ImagePath = fi.Fields.Single(f => f.Name == "Picture").Storage.Get("")

I can't find any Name Field in the FeaturedItemPartRecord table
Thanks,
Samuel

Comment: If you look at the [migrations source code](https://bitbucket.org/nimblepros/orchard-featureditemslider/src/2a12f63b5bf0a29f8a86c7d9bf657a2c60c401f9/Migrations.cs?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#Migrations.cs-54) you can see it attaches a field of type `MediaPickerField` which have its own tables

Comment: so the field was created logically not physically? How do I access it in the table?

Answer (score 3):

That would be an orchard field so it is stored in the Data column of the Orchard_Framework_ContentItemVersionRecord table. It is part of the XML document. Sebastien Ros has a decent blog post explaining orchard's database structure http://sebastienros.com/understanding-orchard-s-database

Answer (score -1):

I think I found it, it's  Projections_StringFieldIndexRecord
Thank you

Comment: Projections index the original field data stored in the contentitemversion table so that they can be queried.

Comment: As @Hazza said this is not really where Orchard stores the data of the field, it is only used for indexing the fields. If you disable the feature 'Projections' you can still use the fields and it won't store its data in the Projections table anymore